# Get cumulative sum based on unique item in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm using MySQL and I'm trying to write a stored procedure query that joins two tables and produces a particular column's running sum. Instead of the usual continuous running sum which is continuous, I would like the one that resets each time the item changes.

I hope what I'm requesting is clearer after my reproducible sample.

**Table 1**

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Item` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Quantity` decimal(5,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Volume` decimal(20,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  );
  
  INSERT INTO table1 (Date, Item, Quantity, Volume)
  VALUES ('2022-04-25', 'Ball', 5, 30),
        ('2022-04-25', 'Balloon', 3, 14),
        ('2022-04-25', 'Bag', 2, 7),
        ('2022-04-24', 'Ball', 7, 20),
        ('2022-04-24', 'Balloon', 1, 9),
        ('2022-04-24', 'Bag', 4, 18),
        ('2022-04-23', 'Ball', 9, 53),
        ('2022-04-23', 'Balloon', 4, 25),
        ('2022-04-23', 'Bag', 11, 12),
        ('2022-04-22', 'Ball', 13, 8);
```

**Table 2**

```
CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Item` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Size (inches)` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `density` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  );
  
  
  
  INSERT INTO table2 (Date, Item, `Size (inches)`, density)
  VALUES ('2022-04-25', 'Ball', 15, 20),
        ('2022-04-25', 'Balloon', 13, 34),
        ('2022-04-25', 'Bag', 12, 17),
        ('2022-04-24', 'Ball', 17, 50),
        ('2022-04-24', 'Balloon', 11, 19),
        ('2022-04-24', 'Bag', 14, 8),
        ('2022-04-23', 'Ball', 19, 3),
        ('2022-04-23', 'Balloon', 14, 5),
        ('2022-04-23', 'Bag', 31, 2),
        ('2022-04-22', 'Ball', 42, 18);
```

This is the stored procedure I have at the moment:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`localhost`@`%` PROCEDURE `procedure1`()
BEGIN

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `procedure_table`;

SET @running_total:=0;

CREATE TABLE `procedure_table` AS SELECT * FROM (
SELECT i.`Item`,
i.`Date`,
ROUND(i.`Volume`/i.`Size (inches)`,2) as `Volume/Size`,
ROUND(i.`Quantity`/i.`Volume`,2) as `Quantity x Volume`,
i.`Size (inches)` as `Size (inches)`,
i.`density` as density,
i.`Quantity`,
ROUND(i.Volume) as `Oil Volume`,
(@running_total := @running_total + IFNULL(i.`Volume`,0)) AS `Cumulative Volume`
FROM (SELECT `table1`.*,
`table2`.`Size (inches)`,
`table2`.`density`
  FROM `table1` 
  LEFT JOIN `table2`
  ON `table1`.Item = `table2`.`Item` 
  AND Month(`table1`.Date) = Month(`table2`.Date)
  AND Year(`table1`.Date) = Year(`table2`.Date)
  ORDER BY `table1`.Item,Date) as i) u;



END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

When I run this I get a table that looks like this:

[image]

When instead I'd what I want is:

[image]

I've tried the `PARTITION BY` function but haven't been able to get it to work in MySQL.

How do I get my desired output?

**Edit - Output without problematic column**

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT i.`Item`,
i.`Date`,
ROUND(i.`Volume`/i.`Size (inches)`,2) as `Volume/Size`,
ROUND(i.`Quantity`/i.`Volume`,2) as `Quantity x Volume`,
i.`Size (inches)` as `Size (inches)`,
i.`density` as density,
i.`Quantity`,
ROUND(i.Volume) as `Oil Volume`
FROM (SELECT `table1`.*,
`table2`.`Size (inches)`,
`table2`.`density`
  FROM `table1` 
  LEFT JOIN `table2`
  ON `table1`.Item = `table2`.`Item` 
  AND Month(`table1`.Date) = Month(`table2`.Date)
  AND Year(`table1`.Date) = Year(`table2`.Date)
  ORDER BY `table1`.Item,Date) as i) u 
  ORDER BY Item;
```

Comment: What version of mysql are you on? select version()

Comment: .. add a query which produces desired output without last column but with explicit ORDER BY which produces needed rows ordering.

Comment: I'm using a MySQL Server version 5.7

Comment: @Akina sorry I don't understand what you asked me to do.

Comment: What is unclear? You post *When instead I'd what I want is:*. The only problematic column for you is the most last "Cumulative Volume", is it? And I ask you to post a query which returns shown output without this problematic column - I'll show how to add it.

Comment: @Akina I understand now, added it as an edit.

Comment: 1) I have asked single query, not stored procedure. 2) I have asked explicit and definite ORDER BY - the most upper SELECT in the query does not contain this clause.

Comment: @Akina sorry, I misunderstood again. I've changed the edit to what you asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Output without problematic column
>
> ```
> SELECT * 
> FROM ( SELECT i.`Item`,
>               i.`Date`,
>               ROUND(i.`Volume`/i.`Size (inches)`,2) as `Volume/Size`,
>               ROUND(i.`Quantity`/i.`Volume`,2) as `Quantity x Volume`,
>               i.`Size (inches)` as `Size (inches)`,
>               i.`density` as density,
>               i.`Quantity`,
>               ROUND(i.Volume) as `Oil Volume`
>        FROM ( SELECT `table1`.*,
>                      `table2`.`Size (inches)`,
>                      `table2`.`density`
>               FROM `table1` 
>               LEFT JOIN `table2` ON `table1`.Item = `table2`.`Item` 
>                                 AND Month(`table1`.Date) = Month(`table2`.Date)
>                                 AND Year(`table1`.Date) = Year(`table2`.Date)
>               ORDER BY `table1`.Item,Date
>              ) as i
>       ) u 
> ORDER BY Item;
> ```

The ordering is not deterministic. Looking your desired output I see that the secondary sorting is performed by `Date` output column. I.e. for correct output rows ordering and cumulative sum calculation the the ORDER BY must be expanded to `` ORDER BY Item, `Date`; ``.

And the query will be:

```sql
SELECT *,
       @sum := CASE WHEN Item = @item
                    THEN @sum + ROUND(i.Volume)
                    ELSE ROUND(i.Volume)
                    END AS `cumulative sum`,
       @item := Item AS Item
FROM ( SELECT i.`Item`,
              i.`Date`,
              ROUND(i.`Volume`/i.`Size (inches)`,2) as `Volume/Size`,
              ROUND(i.`Quantity`/i.`Volume`,2) as `Quantity x Volume`,
              i.`Size (inches)` as `Size (inches)`,
              i.`density` as density,
              i.`Quantity`,
              ROUND(i.Volume) as `Oil Volume`
       FROM ( SELECT `table1`.*,
                     `table2`.`Size (inches)`,
                     `table2`.`density`
              FROM `table1` 
              LEFT JOIN `table2` ON `table1`.Item = `table2`.`Item` 
                                AND Month(`table1`.Date) = Month(`table2`.Date)
                                AND Year(`table1`.Date) = Year(`table2`.Date)
              ORDER BY `table1`.Item,Date
             ) as i
      ) u 
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @item := '', @sum:=0 ) init_variables
ORDER BY Item, `Date`;
```

First additional column either adds current `Oil Volume` to previous one or takes current only depends on the fact does the item is the same like in previous row or not. Second additional column simply stores current `Item` value for to be used on the next row evaluation. These columns can be moved within the output fieldset, but their relative posession must be stored.

PS. If `` (Item, `Date`) `` values pair is not unique then the rows ordering is not definite again. In this case you must either group in the subquery providing this expression uniqueness or expand the ordering expression additionally.